# Bot Framework - Send a response after "x" seconds

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

This is my code:

```
LuisIntent("AboutContact")]     
public async Task AboutContact(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
       await context.PostAsync("Our phone: 9999999999");

PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.AfterSelectionOption, new  String[] { 
"YES", "NO" },"Do you want more info?");
}
```

How I can show that prompt four seconds after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before showing prompt you can use `Task.Delay()`

```
await Task.Delay(4000); // 4 second delay
```

Hope its help to you.